# VueJS - trouble understanding .$set and .$add

Tags: json, vue.js

I am trying to build an array of objects in VueJS and I am running into some issues with `.$set` and `.$add`.

For example, I need the following structure when adding new items/objects:

```
{
  "attendees": {
    "a32iaaidASDI": {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "userToken": "a32iaaidASDI",
      "agencies": [
        {
          "name": "Foo Co"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

New objects are added in response to an AJAX call that returns JSON formatted the same as above. Here is my Vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#trainingContainer',
            data: {
                attending: false,
                attendees: {}
            },
            methods: {
                setParticipantAttending: function(data)
                {
                    if (data.attending)
                    {
                        this.attendees.$add(data.userToken, data);
                    } else {
                        this.attendees.$delete(data.userToken);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This only works if I start with `attendees: {}` in my `data` but when I try `attendees.length` after adding an attendee, I receive `undefined`. If I use `attendees: []`, the new object does not appear to be added. And lastly, if I use `.$set(data.userToken, data)` it does not add in the `'token':{data..}` format required.

What could be the issue here? What is the correct way to use `$.add` when starting with an empty array of objects?

**UPDATE**

I found that it works if I set `attendees: {}` and then, when adding a new object,

```
if (data.userToken in this.attendees) {
    this.attendees.$set(data.userToken, data);
} else {
    this.attendees.$add(data.userToken, data);
}
```

Not sure if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Comment: `$add` no longer exists (v0.6.0)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you set attendees to an empty object (`{}`) it will not have a `length` attribute. That attribute is on Arrays.

If you set attendees to an empty array (`[]`) then you need to use $set (or really, I think you want .push()) – $add is intended for use on objects not on arrays.

I'm not quite following your last question – could you add more context?

EDIT 2:

The answer below was for Vue 1.x. For Vue 2.x and greater use:

```
this.$set(this.attendees, data.userToken, data);
```

More information here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

EDIT:

Responding to your update, you should be able to just use $set in all cases. I.e. just do this:

```
this.attendees.$set(data.userToken, data);
```

Comment: See update. I need to be able to access a unique key for each item in the list so that I can delete it. I found that I can get the count of attendees using `Object.keys(this.attendees).length`. I also found that I have to use `$add` if the new attendee is not in the list already, otherwise `$set`.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score -1):

As of version 0.6.0, this seems to be the correct way:

```
this.someObject = Object.assign({}, this.someObject, { a: 1, b: 2 })
```

http://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change_Detection_Caveats